# access denied when starting a process using impersonation

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, impersonation

I have a class for user impersonation

```
public class Impersonation
    {

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern bool LogonUser(
            string lpszUsername,
            string lpszDomain,
            string lpszPassword,
            int dwLogonType,
            int dwLogonProvider,
            out IntPtr phToken
        );

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr hObject);

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern bool DuplicateToken(
            IntPtr ExistingTokenHandle,
            int SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL,
            out IntPtr DuplicateTokenHandle
        );
public static WindowsImpersonationContext GetWindowsImpersonationContext(TokenImpersonationLevel impersonationLevel)
        {
            IntPtr token = IntPtr.Zero;
            IntPtr tokenDuplicate = IntPtr.Zero;
            WindowsImpersonationContext impersonationContext = null;

            try
            {
                if (LogonUser("username", "domain", "password", 2, 0, out token))
                {
                    if (DuplicateToken(token, (int)impersonationLevel, out tokenDuplicate))
                    {
                        WindowsIdentity identity = new WindowsIdentity(tokenDuplicate);
                        impersonationContext = identity.Impersonate();
                    }
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (token != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    CloseHandle(token);
                }

                if (tokenDuplicate != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    CloseHandle(tokenDuplicate);
                }
            }

            return impersonationContext;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to start a process this way as a different user, but I get an access denied error.
my account does not have access to the file, however, the account with which I am trying to open the file has access to the file. What am I doing wrong?

```
            using (WindowsImpersonationContext impersonationContext = GetWindowsImpersonationContext(TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation))
            {
                Process.Start(filename);
            }
```

at the same time, I can copy files in this way and delete

Comment: Can't you use `ProcessStartInfo.UserName` (and password and domain) instead?

Comment: Is it ok to Close the token handle before actually using the WindowsImpersonationContext ? In the example in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.windowsimpersonationcontext?view=netframework-4.8.1) The token and Identity are kept living beyond the usage of the context and only disposed/closed afterwards.

Comment: If you're sure your code is fine, consider a local permissions issue or a problem with your account information.